# App icon showing in ads, but app not running

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a splash screen. I can see the app icon on the ADB mobile screen, but the app doesn't run. Enclosing the logcat

**Logcat**

```
2020-09-16 17:03:52.612 12836-12836/? I/.example.stree: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-09-16 17:03:52.639 12836-12836/? I/.example.stree: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2020-09-16 17:03:52.641 12836-12836/? W/.example.stree: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-09-16 17:03:52.850 12836-12836/com.example.street I/.example.stree: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-09-16 17:03:53.056 12836-12836/com.example.street E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.street, PID: 12836
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   **
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7244)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxw.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.3.0:27)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.3.0:3)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239)
        ... 10 more
2020-09-16 17:03:53.120 12836-12836/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12836 SIG: 9
```

**This is my manifest xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.street">

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**This is my splash activity xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
tools:context=".SplashActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/just_logo"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/just_logo" />

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/just_logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="32sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main activity file**

```
    package com.example.street;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
  }
```

**Splash activity file**

```
    package com.example.street;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;



    public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Handler handler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_splashscreen);

    handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    },3000);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to AdMob > Apps > View All Apps > Search for your app > Copy the **APP ID** from their

2 - Go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, and copy paste the following line inside the Application tag :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="XXXXXXX"/>
```

3 - Replace **XXXXXXX** with your **APP ID**

Comment: I do not need the admob and would like my app to run without it. So how do I delete that?

Comment: Delete the dependency of `Google Ads`

Comment: Could you guide me on how to delete the dependency of Google Ads?